# calling Python from Java - script not executed properly

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to execute a python script from a java program.
I have a weird problem, while the script is invoked but does not process completly.

to demonstrate this problem I've simplified the scenario to the following:

Java Code:

```
public class CallPython {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python D://test.py narf");
        int res1 = p1.waitFor();
        System.out.println(res1);

        Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python D://test.py narf2");
        int res2 = p2.waitFor();
        System.out.println(res2);

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Python Script:

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
if (a == "narf"):
    sys.exit(10)

file = open('bla.txt', 'w')
file.write("StackOverFlow is AWESOME!!!")
file.close()

sys.exit(5)
```

Running the script from the command line (with an argument different then "narf") results in creation of the file "bla.txt" while running the java code from eclipse prints:
10
5
and creates nothing...

Comment: printout the current working directory; when you run from eclipse it is probably creating the file in a different directory to the one that you are expecting.

Comment: As a side note, don't write `D://test.py`. You don't need to escape forward slashes, only backslashes. Fortunately, in this context, a double forward slash happens to mean the same thing as a single one on (as far as I know) every platform that Java currently runs on, but that isn't actually guaranteed by Java or anything else, and there are other contexts where doubling them can cause problems (e.g., when you build a file: URL, you can confuse Windows).

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, i'll remove the unnecessary slashes..
(embarrassing, i've spent over an hour on this :| )